Failed to install pandas due to error "pytz >= 2011k"
I failed to install pandas due to the following error, what might be wrong? Thanks
Collecting pandas==0.23.4
  Using cached pandas-0.23.4.tar.gz (10.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [4 lines of output]
      <string>:12: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
      error in pandas setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)
          pytz >= 2011k
               ~~~~~~~^
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.


I think that you're dealing with a compatibility issue with your current environment/dependencies.
Do you need Pandas v0.23.4? It's a pretty old version and is probably throwing errors with your pytz. From the pandas documentation, the current supported pytz required dependency is v2020.1. I recommend upgrading both of these to the more recent packages.
Try in your command line:
pip install --upgrade pytz pandas

It is required by pyviz which is what I want to install. The latest version of pandas I can install is 0.25.0, but it is still failed due to the same error.

@zjffdu I see. what python version are you using? have you tried pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel? this could help with the deprecation issue
